# How to handle extremely large data in node.js array

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, sorting

I am working on a Node.js server that responds with JSON. I have a legacy server that contains the data. The Node.js server acts as a middle-man connecting the user to the data. The legacy server returns data as a csv with columns being keys and rows being objects. I want to turn this into an array of json objects. I am using this tool to do just that: https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson. I can either have the tool construct the output for me or I can have a function called with each row passed in and construct it myself. I am currently doing the later.

The users of my application can pass in a search value which means only rows that contain this value should be returned. The user can also pass in filter keys and values which means only rows where key contains value for every key and value given should be returned. They can of course give both search and filter values or neither. They also give a sort key which is the key in the objects to sort the array by. They also give me a sort order: ascending or descending. They also give me a page size and offset to return, which is for pagination.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this with data sets that could contain millions of rows? I can't modify the legacy server. Here is what I have. It works but I would like to improve performance as much as possible. Is there a more efficient way to do the sorting, searching, filtering, pagination, etc? Would it be better to add to the array and then sort instead of using a binary search tree and sorting during add? Is there a way I could use streams to improve performance? I expect the server to be limited by CPU performance not RAM. I am looking for any recomendations for better performance. Thanks! :)

EDIT: Also, what part of the below code is blocking?

```
function searchRow(row, search) {
  if (search) {
    for (var key in row) {
      if (row.hasOwnProperty(key) && row[key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function filterByField(obj) {
  return obj.field === this.valueOf();
}

function filterRow(row, filter) {
  if (filter) {
    filter = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(filter));
    var passed = true;
    for (var key in filter) {
      if (filter.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var index = row[key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[key].toString().toLowerCase());
        passed = passed && (index > -1);
      }
      if (!passed) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return passed;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function orderByKey(key, reverse, a, b) {
  return function (a, b) {
    var x = (a[key] || '').toString().toLowerCase();
    var y = (b[key] || '').toString().toLowerCase();
    if (x > y) {
      return reverse ? -1 : 1;
    } else if (y > x) {
      return reverse ? 1 : -1;
    } else if (hash(a) > hash(b)) {
      return reverse ? -1 : 1;
    } else if (hash(b) > hash(a)) {
      return reverse ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  };
}

function sortedInsert(element, array, key, reverse) {
  array.splice(locationOf(element, array, key, reverse) + 1, 0, element);
  return array;
}

function locationOf(element, array, key, reverse, start, end) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  start = start || 0;
  end = end || array.length;
  var pivot = parseInt(start + (end - start) / 2, 10);

  var c = orderByKey(key, reverse, element, array[pivot]);
  if (end - start <= 1) {
    return c == -1 ? pivot - 1 : pivot;
  }

  switch (c) {
    case -1: return locationOf(element, array, key, reverse, start, pivot);
    case 0: return pivot;
    case 1: return locationOf(element, array, key, reverse, pivot, end);
  }
}

function getTable(path, columns, delimiter, query) {
  var deferred  = q.defer();

  var headers = [];
  var data = [];
  delimiter = delimiter ? delimiter : '\t';

  var converter = new Converter({
    delimiter: delimiter,
    noheader: true,
    headers: columns,
    workerNum: os.cpus().length,
    constructResult: false
  });

  converter.on("error", function(errMsg, errData) {
    deferred.reject(errMsg);
  });

  converter.on("record_parsed", function(row) {
    if (searchRow(row, query.search) && filterRow(row, query.filter)) {
      sortedInsert(row, data, query.sort || headers[0].split("!").pop(), query.order === 'desc');
    }
  });

  converter.on("end_parsed", function() {
    var offset = parseInt(query.offset || 0);
    var limit = parseInt(query.limit || data.length);
    var total = data.length;

    data = data.slice(offset, offset + limit);

    deferred.resolve({
      "total": total,
      "rows": data
    });
  });

  var options = {
    url: config.url + path,
    gzip: true,
    method: 'GET'
  };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    }
  }).pipe(converter);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: You should look into using a database such as MySQL (or MongoDB if you prefer document-based). Databases are made to process large amounts of data and it's much more efficient than loading it into memory.

Comment: If you can't change the legacy server, what you could do is put the data from the legacy server into your own database before you serve it to users. You should also consider caching search results to lessen the load.

Comment: Cache would only be able to be around 60 seconds. Would the overhead of adding the data to a database be worth it?

Comment: If your array does have millions of rows, it would definitely be worth using a database rather than loading the whole thing into memory before searching through it.

Comment: I agree to Zhang, but Alec will have to figure out a way to keep the "new database" always updated.

Comment: `converter.on("record_parsed", function(row) {})`, add each row to a database. Then query with search and filter values, sort, and grab the page. Is that probably my best bet?

Comment: The legacy server has thousand of different resources that it serves and each has a different structure. So the database pretty much has to be updated for each request.